# How to search each line in a text file and capture the lines that starts with DDMMM format?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a text file that contains a credit card statement. I am trying to capture all the lines that are a transaction. As each of these transactions line starts with a date in the format "DDMMM", is there any way to check if the line starts with the "DDMMM" format?

Below is what I have tried.

```
if (line.startsWith(\d\d\w\w\w\s)) {
        indexMap.set('transaction', lineIndex);
        result['transaction'] = parseFloat(textMap.get(lineIndex).trim().split(/\s+/)[2].replace(/\s|,|/g, ''));
      }
    lineIndex++;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
const content = `
08MAR Blah Blah Blah
08M NoBlah NoBlah NoBlah 
09MAR Blah Blah Blah
`;

function parseLine( line ){
    const result = line.match(/^([0-9]{2})([A-Z]{3})(.*)/);
    let data = null
    if(result){
       data = {};
       data.DD = result[1];
       data.MMM = result[2];
       data.detail= result[3];
    }
    return data;
}

content.split(/\n?\r/).map( parseLine ).filter( d => d !== null );
```